# Как перебрать массив из JSON Объектов? php, laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, json, laravel

Опишу подробнее - делаю галерею с загрузкой нескольких изображений на Laravel - у меня в таблице с товарами есть поле - file,  в котором я записываю данные через JSON_encode и получаю такие значения в базе данных -

```
{"path":"sUH7TXv7.jpg"},{"path":"JBGeOqCn.jpg"},{"path":"NWNLQUh5.jpg"}
```

Как я могу перебрать эти значения, чтобы можно было потом перевести его в массив и вывести каждое значение по очереди, для отображения картинок?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, добавить в строку [],  сделав это валидным JSON'ом с массивом объектов

```
$source = '{"path":"sUH7TXv7.jpg"},{"path":"JBGeOqCn.jpg"}'
$json = json_decode('[' . $source . ']');
foreach($json as $img) {
  echo $img->path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно к вашему примеру:

```
$a = '{"path":"sUH7TXv7.jpg"},{"path":"JBGeOqCn.jpg"},{"path":"NWNLQUh5.jpg"}';
$b = explode(',', $a);
$c = array_map('json_decode',$b);
print_r($c);
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [path] => sUH7TXv7.jpg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [path] => JBGeOqCn.jpg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [path] => NWNLQUh5.jpg
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте json_decode со вторым параметром, который делаейт из объекта массив.
Объект лучше привести к такому виду

```
{"path":"sUH7TXv7.jpg","path":"JBGeOqCn.jpg","path":"NWNLQUh5.jpg"}

   $source = '{"path":"sUH7TXv7.jpg","path":"JBGeOqCn.jpg","path":"NWNLQUh5.jpg"}';
   $json = json_decode($source, true);
   foreach($json as $img) {
       echo $img;  // ссылка на картинку
   }
```